# Adding only unique elements to a list from another list

Tags: list, scala, data-structures

I am creating a service that returns lists of articles from an XML feed. I am trying to find a better way to update the list of articles currently stored in my program whenever the client code calls for an update.

I have a variable named articleHistory which is the list of articles I want to update. I have the new list of articles, aptly named newArticles, which my article retrieval function returns. There will be articles which are present in both lists. But the newArticles list will contain articles which are not in the articleHistory list. I am currently using a temporary variable, appending newArticles to articleHistory, and then returning that after calling the distinct method.

```
def updateArticleHistory: List[Article] = {
    val newArticles = getArticles
    val temp = newArticles ::: articleHistory
    articleHistory = temp.distinct
}
```

Assume there is a case class name Article available. I feel there has to be a better way to do this, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: consider using `Set` data structre that in comparison with `List`s guarantee uniquness of element.

Comment: Is your list sorted? If no, is its items order important?

Comment: @VladimirKorenev no, order isn't important.

Comment: Then I support @Mr.V. suggestion to use Set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like what you want is `ListSet`.  A `ListSet` is a `Set` (since it only allows one of each element) but is maintains the insertion order.  The one weird thing is that since it inserts elements at the head, the list is backwards.

```
import collection.immutable.ListSet
val a = ListSet.empty[Int]
val b = a ++ List(3,4,5)        // ListSet(5, 4, 3)
val c = b ++ List(1,2,3,4,5,6)  // ListSet(6, 2, 1, 5, 4, 3)
c.toList.reverse  // List(3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but why you can't do smth like this:

```
val lstA: List[Int] = List[Int](1, 2, 3, 4)
val lstB: List[Int] = List[Int](5, 6, 7, 1, 2)

println(lstA ::: lstB distinct)

>> List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
```

I think it's nice:)

Comment: Thats fundamentally what I'm doing right now. I was trying to find a better solution, if one existed. That is, however, a far more concise way to do it, so thank you for that.